# How to get distinct values based on latest Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this query where I merged two documents and it sorts based on latest date.

```
db.getCollection("filings").aggregate([
{ $sort : { PeriodEndDate : -1 } },
{ $match : {$or: [{"SubType" : "PRESS"},{"SubType" : "INTERIM"}]} },
{ $lookup: {
     from: "coverages",
     localField: "RepoNo",    // field in the filings collection
     foreignField: "RepoNo",  // field in the coverage collection
     as: "fromItems"}},
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt ["$fromItems", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }},
{ $project: { fromItems: 0 } }])
```

How can I only select only one latest PeriodEndDate per duplicated documents where the PeriodEndDate is the latest? When I use $limit it only limits to one. I want to limit each duplicates documents which have the latest date.
I determine the duplicates by 'RepoNo'
Here are two sample documents. I only want to select the first one which has the latest date.

`{ 
    "RepoNo" : "FFF94", 
    "PeriodEndDate" : "2018-06-30 00:00:00.000"
},
{ 
    "RepoNo" : "FFF94", 
    "PeriodEndDate" : "2018-03-31 00:00:00.000"
}`

Comment: how do you determine a duplicate document ?

Comment: I determine it by 'RepoNo'.

Comment: Move the sort after project stage and add the $group stage. Something like `{ $sort : { PeriodEndDate : -1 } },{ $group: { 
          _id: "$RepoNo",  
          latest: {$first:"$$ROOT"} 
        } }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Veeram! Just one more question. Currently, This is the output
`{ 
    "_id" : "F4E80", 
    "data" : {
        "OrgID" : "107467912", 
        "RepoNo" : "F4E80",   "PeriodEndDate" : "2015-12-31 00:00:00.000"
    }
}`
How can I make this only this?

        { 
        "OrgID" : "107467912", 
        "RepoNo" : "F4E80",   "PeriodEndDate" : "2015-12-31 00:00:00.000"
}

Comment: Yw. Add `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot:"$data"}}` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much i gladly appreciate your answer